# iPad Backup without iCloud or PC/Mac

Tags: ipad, backup

Are there apps or appliances available for iPad (or iPhone I suppose) that would allow me to backup the content (photos etc) of my iPad without a PC?

I was thinking of something like Carbonite/JungleDisk or the Apple Time Capsule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently need to go either through iCloud or iTunes (PC/Mac) as per [this kb article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

There are no other solutions that would allow you to do backups of the iPad.

Sorry.

I would strongly recommend you leave a feature request on the feedback page of the [iPad](http://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html) and on the [Time Capsule page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/timecapsule.html). Apple read them and when they get enough request for a feature they get more incentive to implement it.

Comment: Apple MIGHT address this issue if there's sufficient demand AND it fits their strategic product roadmap. I suspect that they'll want to drive people to use iCloud and will not want to provide a local alternative other than a Mac/PC. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out InterConneX from Econ Technologies:
http://www.econtechnologies.com/interconnex/overview.html

InterConneX is free but to connect to a Mac, you need to purchase one of their other applications. It's not a well-known app, but it's quite cool what it can do.